# What is a purpose for returning class in a java method?

Tags: java, class, methods, return, return-value

I'm working with java and have some question about methods, there is no code to correct, only a question for why is good to return into method a class?

```
public class Bird { public Bird bird() {return null;} }
```

Can you explain when and why i should return class from method? And how this gonna work?

Comment: It's not returning a class, it's returning an instance of a class. Returning a class would be `public Class<Bird> bird() { ... }`

Comment: Well, as it's currently written, it's not going to work. You return null, i.e. nothing.

Comment: Why return instance of class?

Comment: Lets assume you have a class `Person` and that person has a child that is also a `Person`. What should `Person getChild()` do if not return the child?

Comment: some pratical use case ?

Comment: It's like asking "why would you do addition?" in math class. There are infinite problems you can solve with that, and choosing just a few that represents them all is impossible. There are so many types of operations that you perform on something of one type, that produces a result that's the same. Calling `toUpperCase` on a String returns a String.

Comment: Okay, i'm hit the notion, thank you all !

Comment: You mean something like many methods of the `String` class like `concat()`, `replace()`, `trim()` that transform the current string into a new string? Or `BigInteger.add()` that adds a two `BigInteger`s together and returns the result as a new `BigInteger`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a must to return class, compiler expects value in return but it does not has to be a class. It depends what you are planning to do with a method, you could return any data type be it int, String, character, Arrays, Object etc or say when you don't want to return anything that's void return type.

if you were to look at method definition,

```
//do whatever
return returnType;
}
```

it clearly has returnType in method definition, which tells compiler what to expect back from method as a return value.

In your example, i do not know the context but the way you posted your method it says Bird as returnType, which means either compiler is expecting you to return BirdType object or you could also return null.

P.S. i didn't have the said reputation to add it to comments :/